# Cannot highlight SELECT statements in IBM DB2 SQL code in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: sql, db2

I want to know how to highlight my SQL statements with IBM DB2 connection in Microsoft Visual Studio. I have DB2 connection but all the text is in black and white and doesn't really work the same way it would in a regular SQL statement. Can anyone assist with this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you installed the correct software to enable the integration?   See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=adonet-db2-integration-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs to be improved, to specify your exact environment, your version of Visual Studio, which Db2-client package(s) and which components you installed alongside Visual Studio.

Specifically you need to ensure that the workstation running Visual Studio also has correctly installed the "IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio" component.

See more about the functionality of the Db2 add-ins at this [page](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=adonet-db2-integration-in-visual-studio), including a link for downloading.  Your Db2 DBA , if you have one, may also be able to help locate the installable.  As usual with any IBM software, only the currently available version along with any fixpacks should be deployed, and also kept up to date regularly.

Comment: I downloaded and installed the package but it doesn't load correctly. I tried deleting the ComponentModelCache folder like it said online in the VS forum but that didn't work. I don't know how to solve this issue. Perhaps the Activity Log could help.

Comment: <entry>
    <record>139</record>
    <time>2022/12/21 18:15:58.302</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>AutoLoadManager</source>
    <description>Autoload request for package {de477cfc-f0a4-4712-bbeb-b72822763a52} for UI context {adfc4e64-0397-11d1-9f4e-00a0c911004f} is ignored because package does not support background loading. See https://aka.ms/AA52xzw for more details.</description>
  </entry>

Comment: Symptom suggests version / fixpack problems.  Edit you question to specify exact versions of Visual Studio and bitness,  which Db2-client you installed (the plain text output of the `db2level` command on your workstation, which version of the IBM add-inn you installed, which operating system you are using (windows build number).

Comment: I reverted from visual studio 2022 to visual studio 2019 and now I'm no longer getting errors and the packages seem to be loading. However, I am trying to get my IBM DB2 SQL statement results to appear in the output from the script editor. The results only display when I use query editor. Not sure how to do that. Help would be appreciated.